# Key/Value Collection that maintains order

Tags: delphi, generics, collections

I need a delphi key/value collection that will allow me to iterate over the collection in the same order the key/value pairs were inserted/added.

`TList<T>` guarantees order but `TDictionary<T1, T2>` does not.

I guess I could always define a `TList<TPair<Key, Value>>` but it would be more cumbersome to work with.

Is there a built-in collection type that would meet my requirements or would wrapping `TList<TPair<Key, Value>>` be my best option? Or perhaps it would be better to have a `TList<Key>` and a `TDictionary<Key, Value>` and iterate through the list.

Comment: A  `TList<TPair<Key,Value>>` sorted on Key is not too bad, because a Key find operation could use a binary search, but a `tree` based data structure is probably what you need.  Note that `TList<TPair<x,y>>` wont  enforce uniqueness, which is something you might also want to implement, if you want to enforce unique keys.

Comment: @WarrenP How will you perform a binary search without holding the keys in order?

Answer (score 3):

If your key type is `string` and your value type is some descendant of `TObject`, use a `TStringList`. Store your values in the `Objects` array property.

```
SL.AddObject('foo', obj1);

SL.Add('bar');
i := SL.IndexOf('bar');
SL.Objects[i] := obj2;
```

Set the `OwnsObjects` property if you need to.

Comment: This gives up O(1) access by key

Answer (score 3):

the [DeHL collections library](https://github.com/pavkam/DeHL) contains a lot of "Ordered Dictionary"-like classes.    The ordered ones use trees (which have order) instead of hash maps which are unordered.

I believe the `TSortedDistinctMultiMap` might be what you need, if you want to enforce uniqueness, and if you don't want to enforce `Key` value uniqueness, then there are other choices (without `Distinct` in the class name) that will be close to what you need.

Update 2017: The DeHL library is no longer maintained.

Comment: The link is dead, I don't think that library is maintained. Further, sorted sounds different from ordered. Sorted typically implies that the order is based on a compare function. Asker wants the insertion order to be maintained.

Comment: I fixed the link but the library is definitely no longer maintained.

Answer (score 0):

The [Spring4D library](https://bitbucket.org/sglienke/spring4d/src/master/) provides dictionaries that are ordered. At the time of writing these are only available on the [develop](https://bitbucket.org/sglienke/spring4d/branch/develop) branch.